# Tag synonyms: [renal-calculi] and [kidney-stones]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tagging

I just noticed that there is a tag for [renal-calculi](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renal-calculi) and [kidney-stones](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kidney-stones). To my understanding, they are the same exact thing. These are exact synonyms so we need to synonymize them. They are both tagged once on the same question, so we need to decided which one to keep. [kidney-stones](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kidney-stones) is simpler, but we already have a [renal](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renal) so [renal-calculi](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renal-calculi) would fit well with that. Let me know what you guys think.

**Edit**: As no one has a high enough score in either of those tags or even sufficient reputation, I've decided to burninate [renal-calculi](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renal-calculi)

Comment: I think you should broaden the scope of this question to whether we should chose over "specialised" terms and "layman" terms.

Comment: Done: [Should we use medical terms or layman's terms as tags?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/107/113)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I propose we keep [kidney-stones](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kidney-stones) as the main tag, and make [renal-calculi](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renal-calculi) a synonym.

For general users, they may not understand medical terms. [kidney-stones](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kidney-stones) is understood by both groups of people, while [renal-calculi](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renal-calculi) is only understood by medical professionals.

Using the generic term will help us reach more audience.

Comment: This approach could work as a general rule. Kant would be happy :)